# Get result of the previous row for a new calculation

Tags: excel, powerquery

Using Power Query, I want to compare a value with the previous value and if it is higher or lower than a threshold %, it will get that new value, otherwise it will keep the previous value as a reference for the next line. In short, I want to keep that value until a significant value occurs (greater than 3%).

I know how to do this in Excel, but I can't do it in Power Query.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your explanation and examples are not entirely clear, but the following may work for you. If it doesn't, minor tweaks are probably all that is necessary.

The code, comments, and exploring the Applied Steps should inform as to the algorithm

```
let

//Change next lines to reflect actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table13"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"Date", type date}, {"Cost", type number}, {"Threshold", Percentage.Type}
        }),

    Costs = List.Buffer(#"Changed Type"[Cost]),

    ResultList = List.Generate(
        ()=>[r=Costs{0}, idx=0],
        each [idx] < List.Count(Costs),
        each [r = if Number.Abs(1-Costs{[idx]+1}/[r]) > #"Changed Type"[Threshold]{[idx]+1}
                    then Costs{[idx]+1} else [r],
                idx=[idx]+1],
            each [r]),

    #"Add Result Column" = Table.FromColumns(
        Table.ToColumns(#"Changed Type") &
        {ResultList}, type table[Date=date,Cost=number, Threshold=Percentage.Type,Result=number])
in
    #"Add Result Column"
```

[image]

Comment: You understood perfectly. And the solution you've found is brilliant, it seems simple but it's not. I was working on a similar function, but I didn't succeed. Thank you very much